# Selecting column values WITHOUT column name

Tags: php, android, sql, select, datatable

I have a table with two columns: title and content.

I want to pick the values in title columns so I execute

```
"SELECT title FROM table"
```

and it returns me this

```
[{"title":"Just a test"},{"title":"Just a test 2"},{"title":"Just a test 3"}]
```

Now my question is simple: how can I pick values `Just a test`, `Just a test 2` and `Just a test 3` without the column's name?

I need the results to be sent to an app using android code so I need them to be like this in order to parse them and fill a listview (otherwise I have to manipulate the results in the android code but I don't know how to do that).

UPDATE: this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'jsonwrapper.php';
mysql_connect("+++++++","++++++++","+++++++++");
mysql_select_db("my_tripleleon");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT titolo FROM articoli");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{       $output[]=$raw;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Using json_decode($q) doesn't print anything...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? In MySQL you can use `group_concat` whereas in Oracle you can use `listagg`. Which one is yours?

Comment: +1 to you Rachcha. i think its nosql

Comment: You're thinking wrong. It's mysql and I'm using a remote database. group_concat is to concatenate the results in a single string and that's not what I was looking for :)
I want an output like the one in my example. Just this. All the ohter parts of code are done (android and php) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of your query to a `$variable` passed by `json_decode()`, as this is the format you're getting.

```
$myvar = json_decode($your_mysql_result, true);
```

This will return you an associative array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Just a test
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Just a test 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Just a test 3
        )

)
```

So for getting the values, you'd do:

```
foreach ($myvar as $item)
  echo "My item is: " . $item->title . "\n";
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Replace this code:

```
while($raw=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{       $output[]=$raw;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

By this one:

```
while($raw=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{       $output[]=$raw['title'];
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: I did so with my answer.

Comment: doesn't work. When called it returns a string containing "Array"

Comment: Sure, because it's an array. Replace `print` by `print_r`. For what it's worth, you're adding the column **values** to an `Array` called `$output`, so use `print_r` or `var_dump` to show the content.

Comment: ok solved. I had to call print(json_encode($output)) and not just $output. Edit your answer so I can accept it ;)

Comment: Done. Now I understood what you were actually trying to do with those values.